# laravel input image return null

Tags: php, laravel, symfony

i have an input file for images 
this is my form INPUT

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label>{{'Ajouter un image'}} </label>
  <input type="file" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="form-control" name="image" required>
</div>
```

and this is my controller

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
   dd(request()->file('image'));
}
```

I just want to test it but it keeps returning null

Comment: `enctype="multipart/form-data"` add in your `form` tag

Comment: @Sohel0415 its there ive add it

Comment: enctype="multipart/form-data" in form tag not in input tag.

Comment: You have to add it in `<form>` tag @GhassenArfaoui

Comment: @SmitRaval dummy mistake thank you alot

Comment: Welcome buddy @GhassenArfaoui

Comment: Possible duplicate of [file upload laravel 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34443451/file-upload-laravel-5)

Answer (score 3):

You need to add `enctype="multipart/form-data"` in `<form>` instead of `<input>`

```
<form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
   <input type="file" class="form-control" name="image" required>    
</form>
```

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that you have to add `enctype="multipart/form-data"` to your `form` instead of input.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are wrong in using request.
Lets change your code into:

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    dd($request->file('image'));
}
```

You don't need to add `enctype="multipart/form-data"` in your input.. put your `enctype="multipart/form-data"` on your `<form>`

Answer (score 0):

Fixed by adding `enctype="multipart/form-data"` in `<form>`.